# Excel IF Greater than & less than formula

Tags: excel

I am trying to put together a logic that can calculate due dates.

1, If 'CELL B' is greater than 'CELL A' by more than 32 days, then add 90 days to 'CELL C' and show the result in 'CELL D'.

2, If 'CELL B' is less than 'CELL A' by 32 days, then add 122 days to 'CELL A' and show the result in 'CELL D'.

We are talking about data type: Dates
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: `=IF(B2-A2>32,C2+90,A2+122)` for example. You didn't say what should happen if it is 32 days difference exactly though.

Comment: You are right, it should be as the following:
=IF(B2-A2=>32,C2+90,A2+122)
Thank you very much!!